# fprintf output is returning unpredictable results

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, printf

My `fprintf()` is returning unpredictable results. I think it is returning the memory address number instead of the data inside the memory address. Can someone have a look at my code and check it out? When I used the `&source` within the `fprintf()` I'm told it is undeclared and when I declare it in the top of the function it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MenuLoop = 0;
int MaxPackets = 4;
int currentPackets= 0;
int menu;

/*********************************************************
* Node to represent a Cat which includes a link reference*
* a link list of nodes with a pointer to a Cat Struct    *
* would be better but this is for illustartion only!     *
**********************************************************/
struct Packet {
int Source;
int Destination;
int Type;
int Port;
char *Data;
struct Packet *next; // Link to next Cat
};

typedef struct Packet node; // Removes the need to constantly refer to struct 

/*********************************************************
* Stubs to fully declared functions below                *
**********************************************************/
void outputPackets(node **head);
void push(node **head, node **aPacket);
node* pop(node **head);
void AddPacket();
void AddPacket();
void SavePacket();
void ShowCurrent();
void ExitProgramme();


main() {

do{

Menu();

} while(menu<4);

}


void AddPacket(){

int option;

/*********************************************************
* pointers for the link list and the temporary P to    *
* insert into the list                                   *
**********************************************************/
node *pPacket, *pHead = NULL;

/*********************************************************
* Create a cat and also check the HEAP had room for it   *
**********************************************************/
pPacket = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
if (pPacket == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: Out of Memory\n");
    exit(1);
}

currentPackets++;
printf("Enter Source Number between 1-1024:\n");

scanf("%i", &pPacket->Source);
printf("Enter Destination Number between 1-1024:\n");
scanf("%i", &pPacket->Destination);
printf("Enter Type Number between 0-10:\n");
scanf("%i", &pPacket->Type);
printf("Enter Port Number between 1-1024:\n");
scanf("%i", &pPacket->Port);
printf("Enter Data Numberbetween 1-50:\n");
scanf("%s", &pPacket->Data);
printf("Do you want to Enter another Packet?");
pPacket->next = NULL;

/*********************************************************
* Push the Cat onto the selected Link List, the function *
* is written so the program will support multiple link   *
* list if additional 'pHead' pointers are created.       *
* Who says you cannot herd cats!                         *
**********************************************************
* NOTE: The push parameters are using references to the  *
* pointers to get round the pass by value problem caused *
* by the way C handles parameters that need to be        *
* modified                                               *
**********************************************************/

push(&pHead, &pPacket);

pPacket = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
if (pPacket == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: Out of Memory\n");
    exit(1);
}

 outputPackets(&pHead);

/*********************************************************
* Display the Link List 'pHead' is passed as a reference *
**********************************************************/


return 0;


do{
    if(currentPackets == MaxPackets);
{
    printf("Packet limit reached please save\n");

}


}while(currentPackets<MaxPackets);

return 0;
}


void outputPackets(node **head)
{

/*********************************************************
* Copy Node pointer so as not to overwrite the pHead     *
* pointer                                                *
**********************************************************/
node *pos = *head;

/*********************************************************
* Walk the list by following the next pointer            *
**********************************************************/
while(pos != NULL) {
    printf("Source: %.4i Destination: %.4i Type: %.4i Port: %.4i \n", pos->Source, pos->Destination, pos->Type, pos->Port);

    pos = pos->next ;
}
printf("End of List\n\n");
}


void push(node **head, node **aPacket)
{
/*********************************************************
* Add the cat to the head of the list (*aCat) allows the *
* dereferencing of the pointer to a pointer              *
**********************************************************/
(*aPacket)->next = *head;
*head = *aPacket;
}

node *pop(node **head)
{
/*********************************************************
* Walk the link list to the last item keeping track of   *
* the previous. when you get to the end move the end     *
* and spit out the last Cat in the list                  *
**********************************************************/
node *curr = *head;
node *pos = NULL;
if (curr == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
   } else {
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        pos = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (pos != NULL) // If there are more cats move the reference
    {
        pos->next = NULL;
    } else {         // No Cats left then set the header to NULL (Empty list)
        *head = NULL;
    }
}
return curr;

}


void SavePacket(Source, Destination, Type, Port, Data){

FILE *inFile ;
char inFileName[10] = { '\0' } ;

printf("Input file name : ") ;
scanf("%s", inFileName) ;

//Open file
inFile = fopen(inFileName, "w+");
if (!inFile)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", &inFile);
exit(0);

}

fprintf(inFile, "Source: %i Destination: %i Type: %i Port: %i Data: %s \n", Source, Destination, Type, Port, Data);
fclose(inFile);

}


void ShowCurrent(){

}

void ExitProgramme(){}

void Menu(){

printf("********Welcome****** \n");
printf("Creator Ben Armstrong.\n\n");
printf("*Please Choose an option*\n");
printf("1. Add a new packet\n");
printf("2. Save current packet to file\n");
printf("3. Show current list of packets\n");
printf("4. Exit\n");

scanf("%i", &menu);

switch(menu)

{
    case 1:
    AddPacket();
    break;

    case 2:
        SavePacket();
    break;

    case 3 :
        ShowCurrent();
    break;

    case 4 :
    ExitProgramme();
    break;

}


}
```

Comment: [Your exact code copied/pasted into ideone.com gives 14 lines with error](http://ideone.com/4rVmiH). You may want to get rid of those errors.

Comment: what line are you having problems with?  your SavePacket function declaration isn't even valid.  You're printing an address as a string in the "unable to open file" fprintf... There are only two fprintfs in your sample code, and only one uses source, but since you didn't specify the variable type in the function declaration, we can't know what it's doing.

Comment: This does not count as an SSCCE ([Simple, Self-Contained, Complete Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Please work on reducing the code to a bare minimum.  It would help to highlight the `fprintf()` calls that are causing you issues — I didn't notice such highlighting when formatting the question.  It also helps to indent the code 'properly' (for SO, spaces not tabs, and 4 spaces per indentation level).

Comment: What i need is for the data scanned into pPacket->source etc to be passed into my savepacket function

Answer (score 2):

Here's part of your problem...

```
inFile = fopen(inFileName, "w+");

if (!inFile)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", &inFile);
    exit(0);    
}
```

I'm pretty sure you mean...

```
inFile = fopen(inFileName, "w+");

if (!inFile)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", inFileName );
    exit(0);    
}
```

Also note that `&inFile` is the address of the `inFile` variable, not the value stored in the FILE pointer.

Additionally, you declare your function prototype for saving the data as follows...

```
void SavePacket(Source, Destination, Type, Port, Data)
```

which says you're passing in a `Source`, a `Destination`, a `Type`, a `Port` and a `Data` argument, but apparently you mean those to be the names, not the types, so the compiler is assuming they are all integers. You need to give them a type and a name...

```
void SavePacket( int Source, int Destination, int Type, int Port, char* Data)
```

and now you can print them...

```
fprintf(
    inFile, "Source: %i Destination: %i Type: %i Port: %i Data: %s \n", 
    Source, Destination, Type, Port, Data 
);
```

But you have a much bigger mess going on, as you're declaring that SavePacket() should receive arguments, but you don't pass arguments to it when you call it...

```
case 2:
    SavePacket();
break;
```

Which should be passing in the variables you need to print. Something like...

```
case 2:
    SavePacket( 
        somePacket->Source, somePacket->Destination, somePacket->Type,
        somePacket->Port, somePacket->Data
    );
    break;
```

But, you could make that easier this way...

```
void SavePacket( struct Packet* packet )
{
    ...

    fprintf(
        inFile, "Source: %i Destination: %i Type: %i Port: %i Data: %s \n", 
        packet->Source, packet->Destination, packet->Type, 
        packet->Port, packet->Data 
    );
}
```

And then call it by passing in the packet...

```
case 2:
{
    struct Packet somePacket;
    GetPacketDataFromSomewhere( &somePacket );
    SavePacket( &somePacket );
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've used your suggetion above and im getting the error, invalid type name 'Packet at Void SavePacket(Packet* packet). Does the Packet* your suggest pass the struct into my function?

Comment: Yeah... sorry... I was in C++ mode... that should be 'struct Packet', not 'Packet' -- edited accordingly.

Comment: Can i ask one more thing, what am i passing in SavePacket(somePacket); as i get an error if i pass (struct Packet* Packet), sorry for the newby questions im very new to C programming

Comment: I presume that you are getting a packet of data from somewhere that you want to write to disk. I can't answer the question of what you're getting or where you are getting it from. That said, see my edit and if that helps clarify it for you... keeping in mind that I have **no** idea what `GetPacketDataFromSomewhere()` would be other than to say that you pass a pointer to your packet in to it and it fills out the values of the fields with something it got from somewhere.